# How do I use custom ConfigurationSections in their own files?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

In the past, I've created custom ConfigurationSections in my app.config files. How do I move the ConfigurationSection to it's own file, independent of my app's main configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your app.config file

```
<configuration>
   <configSections>
        <section name="customSection" type="ABC" />
   </configSections>
<customSection configSource="custom.config"></customSection> //Your own file name is the configSource
```

Create another file called custom.config. Inside of that file:

```
   <customSection>
   //Your config here
   </customSection>
```